# Jasmine/PhantomJS ignoring __defineGetter__ method

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm working in some tests using Jasmine 2.0 and I have a test like this code:

```
describe('My feature test', function () {
    describe('Negative asserts', function () {
        it('Expect location.search not to equal pre-defined value', function () {
            var myQueryValue = '?custom_query=true';

            expect(myQueryValue).not.toEqual(window.location.search);
        });
    });

    describe('Positive asserts', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            window.location.__defineGetter__('search', function () {
                return '?custom_query=true';
            });
        });

        it('Expect location.search to equal pre-defined value', function () {
            var myQueryValue = '?custom_query=true';
            console.log(window.location.search);
            expect(myQueryValue).toEqual(window.location.search);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using a grunt task to run this code using karma and launching Google Chrome (`karma-chrome-launcher`) and PhantomJS (`karma-phantomjs-launcher`) browsers.

In the Google Chrome the test pass perfectly

```
LOG: '?custom_query=true'
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 99 of 99 SUCCESS (2.889 secs / 2.761 secs)
```

But when the test runs in PhantomJS the `__defineGetter__` method are ignored:

```
LOG: ''
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) My feature test Positive asserts Expect location.search to equal pre-defined value FAILED
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 99 of 99 (1 FAILED) (2.528 secs / 2.522 secs)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:**
Already tried `Object.defineProperty` and still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defineProperty` approach fails in PhantomJS with the following error:

> Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property

I could not find a place where this is clearly documented, but the error above makes me wonder if those properties are just not modifiable in PhantomJS.

Same problem was encountered [here](https://github.com/EndangeredMassa/bond/issues/13), a suggested solution in this case was to wrap non-overridable methods with simple user-defined functions that can be overridden in tests:

```
// Wrap search property for testing purposes
function getLocationSearch() {
    return window.location.search;
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm already doing this way, seems to be the best solution to deal with this non-overridable met/props from PhantomJS. Really appreciate your help.